# Regex TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

My datepicker regular expression is trying matches on a null aray. How do I fix it? Not sure what clazz should equal if the array is null. I'm thinking a simple if (matches[1]) { etc } but I'm not sure what to do if matches is null. Clazz is used elsewhere twice in the code. Do I just set clazz to null or zero?

```
    var matches = exp.match(IS_REGEXP);
    var clazz = scope.$eval(matches[1]);
```

Edit: Here's where they use clazz

```
    if (data.lastActivated !== newActivated) {
      if (data.lastActivated) {
        $animate.removeClass(data.lastActivated.element, clazz);
      }
      if (newActivated) {
        $animate.addClass(newActivated.element, clazz);
      }
      data.lastActivated = newActivated;
    }
```

Here's IS_REGEXP

```
                        11111111           22222222
  var IS_REGEXP = /^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+for\s+([\s\S]+?)\s*$/;
```

Double Edit:

Here's the whole function

```
 function addForExp(exp, scope) {
    var matches = exp.match(IS_REGEXP);

      var clazz = scope.$eval(matches[1]);
    var compareWithExp = matches[2];
    var data = expToData[exp];
    if (!data) {
      var watchFn = function(compareWithVal) {
        var newActivated = null;
        instances.some(function(instance) {
          var thisVal = instance.scope.$eval(onExp);
          if (thisVal === compareWithVal) {
            newActivated = instance;
            return true;
          }
        });
        if (data.lastActivated !== newActivated) {
          if (data.lastActivated) {
            $animate.removeClass(data.lastActivated.element, clazz);
          }
          if (newActivated) {
            $animate.addClass(newActivated.element, clazz);
          }
          data.lastActivated = newActivated;
        }
      };
      expToData[exp] = data = {
        lastActivated: null,
        scope: scope,
        watchFn: watchFn,
        compareWithExp: compareWithExp,
        watcher: scope.$watch(compareWithExp, watchFn)
      };
    }
    data.watchFn(scope.$eval(compareWithExp));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `clazz` to null or empty string shall do, if clazz is all your concern.

```
var clazz = matches ? scope.$eval(matches[1]) : '';
```

But with `compareWithExp`, it might be better to exit from the whole logic when there is no match:

```
if ( ! matches ) return;
```